# I want to create variable from dataframe and need to use in spark scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create variable from dataframe and need to use in spark scala code (i want to go for each row 1 by 1 and use column value in variable each time, can someone help ?
Here is y dataframe :

```
\+---+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|id |table1_name         |table_1_path                                                      |table2_name                |table_2_path                                                             |key_column|
\+---+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|1  |orders-201019-002101|C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Notes/datset/week11/orders-201019-002101.csv|orders-201019-002101 - Copy|C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Notes/datset/week11/orders-201019-002101 - Copy.csv|order_id  |
|2  |orders-201019-002101|C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Notes/datset/week11/orders-201019-002101.csv|orders-201019-002101 - Copy|C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Notes/datset/week11/orders-201019-002101 - Copy.csv|order_id  |
\+---+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

I tried using list but it seems very difficult in scala

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the DF to a list, then use map to apply a scheme to the list. That way you can access the df data as variables.

Example:

```
 case class schemeExemple(
                           valueOne: Int,
                           valueTwo: Int
                          )

  val values = Seq((0,1),(0,1),(10,1),(2,1),(4,1))

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(values)

  val dfList = df.collect().toList.map(x => schemeExemple(x.getInt(0), x.getInt(1)))

  dfList.foreach(x => {
    println(s"Print value one -> ${x.valueOne}")
    println(s"Print value Two -> ${x.valueTwo}")
    println("-----------")
  })
```

Output:

```
Print value one -> 0
Print value Two -> 1
-----------
Print value one -> 0
Print value Two -> 1
-----------
Print value one -> 10
Print value Two -> 1
-----------
Print value one -> 2
Print value Two -> 1
-----------
Print value one -> 4
Print value Two -> 1
-----------
```